# Completely remove border from razor table

Tags: razor, html-table, blazor

I want to make a table in a blazor razor component that has no visible borders at all. I am using it only to order elements.

For example, this is what a table with "border="0"" looks like (taken from the Wetaher service that the Blazor template in Visual Studio starts with):

[image: table example]

I want to remove the lines between the rows and between the header and body of the table. I've tried "border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"" but it does nothing.

Comment: This is an abuse and misuse of the table element. Use div elements instead.

Comment: @enet, how do I put one div below the other, aligned like in a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your default stylesheet file, you can create a custom css class that can override existing bootstrap class.

```
.table-borderless th,
.table-borderless td,
.table-borderless thead th,
.table-borderless tbody + tbody {
    border: 0;
}
```

**How To:**

```
<table class="table table-borderless"></table>
```

Note: use `border: 0 !important;` only if above change is not reflecting.